# How to generate JSON data incremental?

Tags: ruby, json

I have a data file about 1000000 lines, 300+ Mb. I want to convert it to a JSON file.

`JSON.generate` and `Hash.merge` can help generate JSON, but I need to wait for the program to generate one whole hash. That costs too much time.
I want to write JSON to file incrementally.

Here is my code:

```
require 'yajl/json_gem'
my_hash = {}
fd1 = File.open("foo.json", "w")
fd2 = File.open("foo.log")
fd2.each_line do | line |
  l = fd2.lineno
  remote_addr = line.split(" ")[0]
  time_local = line.split("]")[0].split("[")[1]
  item = {l => {:remote_addr => remote_addr, :time_local => time_local}}
  # {
  #   1: {
  #     remote_addr: "1.2.3.4",
  #     time_local: ""
  #   }, 
  #   2: {
  #     ...
  #   },
  #   ...
  # }
  my_hash.merge!(item)
end
fd2.close
fd1.puts JSON.generate(my_hash)
fd1.close
```

Here is my data:

```
// access.log
1.2.3.4 - - [02/Apr/2014:03:23:06 +0800] "GET /index" 200 1 "http://foo" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

--

edit:

Actually, I'd better convert raw data like this:

```
[
  {
     id: "1",
     remote_addr: "1.2.3.4",
     time_local: "02/Apr/2014:03:23:06 +0800"
  }, 
  {
   ...
  },
  {
  ...
  }
]
```

Comment: JSON is an easy format to create incrementally using code, but without examples of your data that's about as far as we can go. A minimal example of the data is needed. Seeing code you've written toward solving the problem would also help because it's better we try to fit something into your code than you try to rewrite yours or shoehorn something in.

Comment: @theTinMan I've added my codes and data.

Comment: You didn't supply a desired output. Also, your sample code isn't valid. `lone` isn't defined.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry for my typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic code to generate a valid JSON output based on the sample line:

```
require 'json'


lines = [
  '1.2.3.4 - - [02/Apr/2014:03:23:06 +0800] "GET /index" 200 1 "http://foo" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"',
  '1.2.3.5 - - [03/Apr/2014:03:23:06 +0800] "GET /index" 200 1 "http://foo" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"'
]

lines.each_with_index do |line, l|
  puts '{' if l == 0
  remote_addr, time_local = /^(\S+) .+ \[(.+)\]/.match(line).captures
  print '"%d":{"remote_addr":"%s","time_local":"%s"}' % [l + 1, remote_addr, time_local]
  puts ',' if l + 1 < lines.size
end
puts "\n}"

# >> {
# >> "1":{"remote_addr":"1.2.3.4","time_local":"02/Apr/2014:03:23:06 +0800"},
# >> "2":{"remote_addr":"1.2.3.5","time_local":"03/Apr/2014:03:23:06 +0800"}
# >> }
```

You'll need to convert the code to read and write files, or maybe read a single file and redirect the output to capture it. You'll also need to figure out how to determine the number of lines in a file to make it possible to find the places to output the commas. It's easy, and I know examples of doing that exist here on Stack Overflow.

In your original code you need to use the block form for `open`, rather than assigning to a variable and then explicitly closing the files; Using the block form of `open` is the Ruby-way. Also, use `File.foreach` to read through a file line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

@theTinMan posted a good answer, I will just add that a little more generic solution for a list of JSON object is to construct the list yourself, but let JSON generate each item:

```
fd1.puts '{'
fd1 = File.open("foo.json", "w")
fd2 = File.open("foo.log")
first_line = true
fd2.each_line do | line |
  fd1.puts(',') unless first_line
  first_line = false
  l = fd2.lineno
  remote_addr = line.split(" ")[0]
  time_local = line.split("]")[0].split("[")[1]
  fd1.print "\"#{l}\": #{JSON.generate(:remote_addr => remote_addr, :time_local => time_local)}"
end
fd1.puts "\n}"
```